# how to use anfendge epub sdk on android to display an epub file

Tags: android, epub

Epub formats have been giving me a lil headache for some time now. Im developing an app thats going to display a book in epub format. iv tried several libraries but the one that seems to catch me is **Anfendge EPUB-SDK** [AnFengDe / EPUB_SDK](https://github.com/AnFengDe/EPUB_SDK)

But it comes off a little unclear and i dont really understand how to display me own books with it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the very page you linked, there are 2 "Getting started" PDF files:

https://github.com/AnFengDe/AnFengDe_EPUB/blob/master/GettingStartedWithEPUBUIComponent.pdf

https://github.com/AnFengDe/AnFengDe_EPUB/blob/master/GettingStartedwithEPUBSDK.pdf

containing all the information you need to use that SDK